# Querying data from result of first hierarchy to query data on second hierarchy

Tags: mysql

I am using column of data from first table of hierarchy to do the next query on second table of hierarchy.

1st Query (from **Courses** table) - 1st hierarchy:

```
“Select course_id, record_id from Courses”
```

Let’s say if we got this results:

```
course_id   | record_id
1417        |  555555
2203        |  444444
3765        |  222222
```

I would like to use data **course_id** got from 1st query as an **Index** to do the next query.

2nd Query (from **Sections** table) - 2nd hierarchy:

Not sure what would be the best query to put the logic together.

Here are some of queries that I tried:

```
“Select section_id, course_id from Sections where course_id in ...? 

"Select course_id from (select course_id from Courses) as cid from Sections.." ?
```

Can I do this?

```
"Select section_id, course_id from Sections where course_id = (select course_id FROM Courses )" ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn´t understood well your 2nd query but I think the JOIN command is your solution here:

```
SELECT C.section_id, C.course_id 
FROM Courses C
JOIN Sections S ON C.course_id = S.course_id
[...]
```

After that you can add the WHERE keyword if you want to apply some restrictions on  S.course_id or something else if you want to order them. Just make sure you use the S.course_id which is a pointer to the Sections table.